# How to add "source" caption and a small logo image under a chart in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I'm making a chart in D3.js, but I need an expert help how to put a data "source" caption under the chart and a small image/logo.

This is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>

<script>

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 40, left: 90},
    width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// csv data
d3.csv("XYZ.csv", function(data) {
        
  // Add X axis
  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range([ 0, width]);
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(function(d){
             return "$" + d;
        }).ticks(10))
        .selectAll("text")
      .attr("transform", "translate(-10,0)rotate(-45)")
      .style("text-anchor", "end");

        
  // Y axis
  var y = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([ 0, height ])
    .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.country; }))
    .padding(.1);
  svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))

  //Bars
  svg.selectAll("myRect")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", x(0) )
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.country); })
    .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.price); })
    .attr("height", y.bandwidth() )
    .attr("fill", "red")

})

</script>
```

the data points from the csv file are as follows: [csv file data points with two columns "country" and "price"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZ3oK.png)

Would you be able to help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the image and caption as regular HTML. Your HTML will look like this:

```
<div id="my-dataviz">
<img src="imagefile.jpg">
<svg/>
<p class="caption">Your caption</p>
</div>
```

And then your d3 selection will look like this:

```
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz svg")
```

Comment: Thank you @rgutterson. I'll try like that. Do you know whether the caption will appear at the bottom of the chart if I do it like that?

Comment: That is correct. If you want it to show up above the visual, just move the <p> tag above the <svg/> tag.